# How do I select a mouse hovered object with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of dynamically generated div-tags with a class-attribute but no id.

How do I select the one which is hovered with mouse cursor?
In CSS it would be like this: div.classname:hover

Oh, and I wouldn't like to use any extra Jquery-plugins.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('div.classname').hover(
    function mouseover() { /* do something */}, 
    function mouseout()  { /* do other thing */}
);
```

EDIT: Thanks, Micah!

Comment: Don't forget to show how to select by class: $('.myDivClassname').hover()